# Validate RGB color without regExp

Tags: javascript

My code is giving unexpected output. I am trying to return boolean value if input is entered as RGB ("rgb(255,255,255)").
Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

```
function checkRGB(input) {
  var i, elem, validRGB;
  validRGB = false;
  // if input is within “rgb(”x,x,x“)“, should continue to execute
  if((input.slice(0, 4) === "rgb(") && (input.slice(-1) === ")")) {

   // Getting only "x, x, x," elements and make them array;
    elem = input.slice(4, -1).split(",");

    // Looping through array elements
    for(i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      elem[i] = parseInt(elem[i]);

      // if array elements > 0 and <= 255 , return true;
      if((elem[i] >= 0 && elem[i] <= 255)) {
        validRGB = true;
      }
    }

  }
  return validRGB;
};

checkRGB("rgb(0,0,300)"); // returns true;  should be false;
checkRGB("rgb(0,-1,0)"); // returns true;  should be false;
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!
thank you

Comment: Since I saw [your previous question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048550/), let me ask again, Why are you doing these checks exactly? Is it to get valid CSS <color> values? In such case, don't do it yourself, there are easier methods. And don't you care about `rgba()`? Also note that even if the current error is fixed, you will still have false positives like `checkRGB('rgb(0foo,1bar,2baz)')`. You should rather convert to Number instead of calling `parseInt`. But this is not enough for the as well valid notation `rgb(r%, g%, b%)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `else` statement and `break` the loop

```
if ((elem[i] >= 0 && elem[i] <= 255)) {
  validRGB = true;        
} 
else {
  validRGB = false;
  break;
}
```

Comment: Or even just return.

Answer (score 0):

The returning value is determined by last elem.

+maybe my answer is not enough
The problem is, you are examining three values.
On example rgb(0,0,300), second loop makes validRGB to true, and third one would be skipped because 300 is not bigger than 0 nor less then 255.

On the other hand, "rgb(0,-1,0", second loop makes validRGB to false. but It changed true at third loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

as per your code if last one of color(B in RGB) is `<=255`  it will returns true.

so you need to code as if in any case if the color code `>255` and '<0' returns false

so make some changes to it if in any case it will be `false` then break the code.

```js
alert(checkRGB("rgb(0,0,300)"));

function checkRGB(input) {
  var i, elem, validRGB;
  validRGB = false;
  // if input is within “rgb(”x,x,x“)“, should continue to execute
  if((input.slice(0, 4) === "rgb(") && (input.slice(-1) === ")")) {

   // Getting only "x, x, x," elements and make them array;
    elem = input.slice(4, -1).split(",");

    // Looping through array elements
    for(i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      elem[i] = parseInt(elem[i]);

      // if array elements > 0 and <= 255 , return true;
      if((elem[i] >= 0 && elem[i] <= 255)) {
        validRGB = true;
      }
      else
      {
      validRGB = false;
      break;
      }
      
    }

  }
  return validRGB;
};
```

Comment: your code is not correct 
Check for alert(checkRGB("rgb(0.1,0,30)"));

Comment: This answer was written based on OP question. its not my own answer. i just suggested changes for question he asked.